# Why is CurrencyConvert so slow?

Tags: curated-data, finance, timing

```
Map[
 QuantityMagnitude@
   CurrencyConvert[DatedUnit["USDollars", #], DatedUnit["Euro", #]] &,
  Range[2008, 2015]]
(* {0.683367, 0.719004, 0.754938, 0.718962, 0.778094, 0.753209, \
0.753825, 0.888133} *)
```

This simple download takes 5 seconds, which is significantly slower than downloading hundreds of share prices with `FinancialData`.

Also, very often I get the following message:

> "A network operation for InflationAdjust timed out. Please try again later."

and one or more values are missing.

Any idea how I can speed this up and how I can avoid the timeouts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a certain improvement using `WolframAlpha`.

To get the rates for the last 20 days I wrote:

```
GetRates[c1_, c2_] :=
 With[{rt = WolframAlpha["Exchange rate " <> c1 <> " " <> c2, {{"History", 1}, "FormattedData"}]},
  Round[#, 0.01]& @ Take[Cases[rt, {DateObject[__], a_Real} :> a/100, Infinity], -20]]

GetRates["USDollars", "Euro"]
```

{0.95, 0.94, 0.92, 0.94, 0.93, 0.93, 0.92, 0.91, 0.92, 0.91, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.93, 0.93, 0.92, 0.91, 0.91}

This is still slow (3 seconds), but much faster than the approach in the question (13 seconds).

Above all : I don' t get timeouts anymore, because `WolframAlpha` employs in this case the option

```
TimeConstraint -> {30, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}
```